# Visual Studio Code is breaking self-closing tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, format

First, I'm a complete newb and I apologize if I'm asking a stupid question in a stupid place.

I'm using Visual Studio Code (VSC) to edit JavaScript and, on each and every save, it's breaking a self-closing tag by adding extraneous spaces.

I'm trying to save this:

```
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

but on saving the file, VSC modifies "" to be "< App / >":

```
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've tried "< App />", still no luck.

I haven't tried to run it, so maybe it works regardless.  However, it breaks syntax recognition by VSC, making following along with my code more of a challenge than it ought to be.

I've been using VSC for a couple months now and it's never done this before.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could be an extension... which ones do you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

To disable auto format on save, add the following to your settings.json file:

```
{ 
   "editor.formatOnSave": false 
}
```